# Decrease consume rate on RabbitMq server

Tags: performance, rabbitmq, monitoring, benchmarking

We are running production single server RabbitMQ (3.7) where around 500 mobile applications are connected as producers (MQTT) and around 10 server applications as consumers. Those 500 publishers push messages basically into one queue and less often in the another one.

Recently we had issue with spikes of stacked messages in all our queues. Numbers of stacked messages went from 1 to 1000. This spike was caused by decrease of consumer rate.

I tired to find what happened and how to eliminate spikes in queues and I should limit queue length or eliminate connections. But we can’t limit we have to perform better. I took a look into RabbitMQ memory usage, cpu and same for consumers everything looks fine and RabbitMq was running around 50% on total load same for memory. Also consumers doesn’t seems to be a bottleneck because consume rate went event higher after the queue length grown.

I have a couple of questions:

- Is RabbitMQ designed for such a large amount of consumers?
- I read that each queue is single threaded is it possible that rabbit just can’t handle 500 producers in one queue and throughput gets lower?
- What else I can use to tackle the cause of lower consumer rate? Number of threads in Rabbit?
- What do you recon to measure or test benchmark/performance of RabbitMQ server?

[image]

Comment: Your use-case appears to be well within RabbitMQ's capabilities. How can you be _certain_ the problem is with RabbitMQ and not your consumers? You say you have 500 publishers, but don't say how many consumers. We also don't know anything about your environment - hardware, RAM, disk, or even the exact version of RabbitMQ and Erlang you're using. For benchmarks, many MQTT benchmark tools exist, and the RabbitMQ team makes PerfTest available to benchmark AMQP.

Comment: I wrote there is 10 consumers running on Java. Rabbit runs on 4G Ram machine on AWS. It's hosted by https://www.cloudamqp.com and using plan Roaring Rabbit.

Comment: Given the information provided, there is no evidence this is a problem with RabbitMQ. Neither your producer nor consumer count is that high. More than likely the problem is in your consumer code - perhaps processing some messages takes longer than you think and causes these backups. Run some benchmarks using PerfTest next, then run MQTT-specific benchmarks, and you'll probably see it's not RabbitMQ.